# JS Retorno valor función

Tags: javascript, funciones

yo quiero invocar mi función y pasar un argumento que están definidos en el switch como case para q me muestre el prompt del switch según vaya pasando los argumentos.

Ejemplo pedir('a') me tendría que dar 'tu no es excelente' pero no hace nada .

Este es el código.

Un saludo.

```js
    function pedir(nota) {
    
    nota = prompt('Introduce la letra de tu calificacion')
    
    
    switch (nota) {
    
    case 'a': prompt('Tu nota es Exelente')
    
     break;
    
    case 'b': prompt('Tu nota es buena')
    
     break;
          
    case 'c': prompt('Tu nota es deficiente')
    
     break;
    
    case 'd': prompt('Tu nota es mala')
    
     break; 
    
    case 'e': prompt('Tu nota es muy mala')
    
     break; 
    
    case 'f': prompt('Tu nota es suspenso')
    
     break;    
    
    return nota;
          
    default : prompt('introduce una letra de la A a la F');
    
      }
    
     }   
    pedir('a');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo saca `nota = prompt('Introduce la letra de tu calificacion')`,cambia tus `prompt` por `alert` y elimina del `return` :

```js
function pedir(nota) {
    switch (nota) {
        case 'a':
            alert('Tu nota es Excelente')
            break;

        case 'b':
            alert('Tu nota es buena')
            break;

        case 'c':
            alert('Tu nota es deficiente')
            break;

        case 'd':
            alert('Tu nota es mala')
            break;

        case 'e':
            alert('Tu nota es muy mala')
            break;

        case 'f':
            alert('Tu nota es suspenso')
            break;
        default:
            alert('introduce una letra de la A a la F');
    }

}

nota = prompt('Introduce la letra de tu calificacion')
pedir(nota);
```

Comment: Genial tío ya funciona , pero no del todo,ahora como puedo pedir al usuario q introduzca la letra de su nota?

Comment: Ahí lo modifiqué @Allan

Comment: Genial Jaime  muchísimas gracias.